# Why do I need a certificate to pin an SSL connection with AF Networking 2?

Tags: tls, ios

I am using the AF Networking 2 library and read that I need to include the server's certificate [here](http://www.dodyrw.com/ssl-pinning-with-afnetworking-2/).

The client should be able to tell that the certificate is valid when it connects to the server, so why do I need to include a copy in my code?

Comment: Server return certificate when ssl connection established. So client have not got a certificate of server. Http client get it from server during ssl connection established.

Comment: Certificate is verified as follows: customer looks what a certificate signed by the certificate, and sees that he has this certificate in the trusted list.

Comment: Browser - this is client too. So, why browser can verify, but iOS http client can't to do this?

Comment: thanks for improve my question (with my bad english) and for patience.

Comment: No problem, sorry it took such a long exchange to figure out what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is specifically because you are doing pinning.  This would allow it to work regardless of if you had a self-signed certificate or a CA signed one.  Basically, you are including the certificate with the application and telling the application specifically "this certificate is valid".

While this does prevent connecting to a different certificate and should allow for use of a self-signed cert, it also complicates revocation of a certificate quite severely since the application would actually have to be updated before you could update the server side certificate.

Personally, I'd avoid using a library that required this.  Even if you wanted to do a self-signed certificate, the better way to do it is to setup your own CA and tell the application to trust the CA root certificate.  Then you can still do normal revocation and change the certificate.

The library you are working with may or may not support this, but that part would be a programing question rather than a security one.

Comment: In those article i read that certificate is validly generated (not self-signed). So i true understand you, that this is strange library?

Comment: "Or if you own the web service, buy a SSL certificate for your domain." - this mean that validly generated?

Comment: I don't see anything in that article you linked that indicates they are using a signed certificate.  A self-signed certificate is perfectly valid, it just isn't trusted.  The second paragraph seems to indicate this to be the case.  It is also possible they did their own SSL implementation and didn't bother to hook in to the trusted root certificates on the device.

Comment: Hmm, I do agree that that second line is suggesting getting a signed cert.  My guess is that it isn't actually necessary and that they don't know how to do a trust check.  I'd personally probably try to find a different library.  That one seems rather limited and may have other flaws.

Comment: AFNetwoking2 checks certificates by default. If you are not using self signed certificate and you are not trying to prevent the user from sniffing his/her own traffic using a proxy you can safely chose not to pin any certificate. This will be ok for most applications.

Answer (score 0):

The client will be able to see that the certificate is valid without pinning the certificate. The client will check the issuer of the certificate, and the issuer of the issuer of the certificate and so on until it finds the root certificate. If the root certificate is installed on your phone it will treat the server certificate as valid.

A malicious user could create a new certificate authority and issue a certificate for the name of your server. The phone's app will not know that this is a certificate created by the user if the user install the root certificate on the phone.

This makes it possible for the user to route the HTTPS traffic thru a proxy and is then able to analyze the traffic. If you want to make this a lot harder to do for the user you can pin the certificate. In that way the client will only connect to a server with the exact certificate that is pinned.

This does not make it impossible to sniff the traffic but it makes it **a lot** more complicated.

Comment: Why library not do check issuer of certificate and issuer of issuer of certificate and so on by default without pinninig certificate?

Comment: It should do, if it does not check the certificate chain by default (without pinning the certificate) it should be reported as a bug on the AFNetworking project. I am actually quite certain that it will check the certificate path by default, at least if you use the latest version which I believe is 2.20

Comment: Thanks. After read post, which is above, i think, that library don't check certificate.

Comment: Well it most certainly does check the certificate. AFNetworking is a very well-used library. However just checking the certificate is not always enough as I describe above. If you are transferring very sensitive info it is a good idea to pin the certificate. Pinning is not required to verify that the certificate is correct and trusted but can increase security even more by making sure it is the exact certificate you expect.